# Advice about a simple admin/user system on bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I study software engineering and i dont know too much about web so i'm looking to learn a bit about web design and i find bootstrap a nice and easy way to do it, im looking to build a system similar to Moodle but way more simple.

I want to make a system where there's an administrator that registers the teachers and the students, you assing a teacher to a student and both of them are capable of leaving messages to each other.

If there is already something close to an open source project alike, i would like you to let me know :), if not, i'd like some advice about this, thank you!

Edit: I think i may be using MySQL for the DataBase :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's available open-source wise as a compete project but if you want to learn, then why not start from scratch and build it.

I recently discovered the Roda framework. It's very powerful but also very simple : here is a project I did to play around. https://github.com/brentgreeff/flatten

There are some links in the readme to learn from. If this is new to you, then you will need to spend a lot of time on it, but you will learn a huge amount. Will totally pay off if you persevere.

Lastly, consider this. Your talking about concepts like : Student and Teacher. What makes a Student different from a teacher? Is it possible that a Student could also teach someone or that a Teacher could be a Student to someone else?

I recommend that you write tests which explain what the user is going to do, i.e. Define the user journeys, rather than starting with database tables.